# Can't enter credential in TeamViewer 13 with i3 window manager

Tags: arch-linux, teamviewer, i3-window-manager

TeamViewer 12 works correctly but it seems that I need version 13 to connect to a TV13-equipped desktop.
[On AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&SeB=nd&K=teamviewer&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=50&do_Search=Go) I see that version 13 corresponds to `teamviewer` and `teamviewer-beta` packages only, so I think should get one of the two (and not others) working in order to connect to a computer with only TV13 installed.

Unfortunately, as in the title, I can't enter username and password to access my account. (Red- and green-highlighted areas in the following screenshot represent object with which I can't/can interact.)

Note that the first few times I tried, the first box was **not** already filled with my e-mail, then it get filled, maybe because I installed TV12 and made access.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error comes because for some reason, which I cannot understand, on some builds of linux, Teamviewer doesn't get through your router, firewall or some other blocking device. This results in the client not allowing input in any field which would end up sending information to their servers. If you look down to the bottom left of that image, sending information isn't going to work because there is no connection to the server.

The solution to this is either to manually punch a hole for your computer through the ports on your router or firewall, or, there is another solution floating around which involves installing  a package called libnss-resolver. I installed that same package on my laptop which is running KDE, which had the same problem and rebooted TV and it got a connection, however this may not work for you.

On my desktop machine, which has a static IP, I manually blew a hole through the ports that Teamviewer likes to use and as a result it will only work with that device on my network, but that certainly made the issue a negative.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Can you give me some more detail about the router-related solution?